# How to get page number of tikzmark markers?

Tags: tikzmark, atbegshi

Given the following example using the `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \foreach \n in {A,B} {%
        \ifnum\arabic{page}=\tikzmarkpage{\n}
            \tikz[remember picture, overlay]
                \node[draw=blue] at (pic cs:\n) {\n};
        \fi
    }
}}

\newcommand\tikzmarkpage[1]{%
    % How to return the actual page number of marker #1 here?
    \arabic{page}%
}

\begin{document}
\tikzmark{A}
\newpage
\tikzmark{B}
\end{document}
```

In this version the marks `A` and `B` are defined on different pages, but looping through all nodes in the `\AtBeginShipout` hook makes *all* nodes being displayed on every page on top of each other. I know `tikzmark` already stores the page number the marker was defined on, I don't see a way to extract that information to use it for a check in the `\foreach` loop, though.

So how would you define `\tikzmarkpage` to get the corresponding page number for the given marker name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use \arabic if you want to get a number, depending on the language this isn't a number.

Beside this should work (but I didn't test complicated page numbering setups):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutUpperLeft{%
    \foreach \n in {A,B} {%
        \ifnum\number\value{page}=0\tikzmarkpage{\n}
            \tikz[remember picture, overlay]
                \node[draw=blue] at (pic cs:\n) {\n};
        \fi
    }
}}



\newcommand\tikzmarkpage[1]{%
 \ifcsname save@pt@#1\endcsname
  0\csname save@pg@\csname save@pt@#1\endcsname\endcsname
 \fi}

\begin{document}


\tikzmark{A}

\newpage
\tikzmark{B}
\end{document}
```